# For the purposes of being eligible for a Nebula award, what counts as "science fiction, fantasy, or a related fiction genre"?

Tags: awards, genre

I was looking at [the rules for the Nebula awards.](https://nebulas.sfwa.org/about-the-nebulas/nebula-rules/) It turns out that the rules governing the award specifically state that a work has to belong to "the genres of science fiction, fantasy, or a related fiction genre":

> 6. Eligibility
>
>    a. All works first published in English, in the United States, during the calendar year, in the genres of science fiction, fantasy, or a related fiction genre are eligible for the Nebula Awards® in their respective categories.

However, I read the entire rules document, and I couldn't find a definition of "science fiction, fantasy, or a related fiction genre" anywhere in the document. Which naturally leads to the question: for the purposes of deciding whether a work is eligible to be nominated for a Nebula award, what does "science fiction, fantasy, or a related fiction genre" mean?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted... it seems like a reasonable question to me. I upvoted.

Comment: @EJoshuaS It may just be a matter of opinion, since the rule quoted is fairly vague, and the categories left undefined (apparently).

Comment: From the part you left out: "2. The Nebula Awards Commissioner will decide the eligibility of a questionable work." It sounds like the boundaries of science fiction, fantasy, and "related fiction" are up to the discretion of the Commissioner.

Comment: @Mick If they did, in fact, leave the categories undefined, that's actually an answer to the question (assuming, of course, there's evidence for that).

Comment: @user14111 interesting! I would love an answer that looks at the various ways different commissioners have drawn the line.